# How to call a Javascript method in iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webview

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/quiz-1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<p class="question">1. What is the answer to this question?</p>        

<ul class="answers">            
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">Answer 1</label><br/>          
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">Answer 3</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d"><label for="q1d">Answer 4</label><br/>       
</ul>        


<p class="question">2. What is the answer to this question?</p>        

<ul class="answers">            
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a"><label for="q2a">Answer 1</label><br/>           
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b"><label for="q2b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2c"><label for="q2c">Answer 3</label><br/>           
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="d" id="q2d"><label for="q2d">Answer 4</label><br/>       
</ul>        

<p class="question">3. What is the answer to this question?</p>        

<ul class="answers">            
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" id="q3a"><label for="q3a">Answer 1</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" id="q3b"><label for="q3b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" id="q3c"><label for="q3c">Answer 3</label><br/>           
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="d" id="q3d"><label for="q3d">Answer 4</label><br/>       
</ul>        

<p class="question">4. What is the answer to this question?</p>        

<ul class="answers">           
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="a" id="q4a"><label for="q4a">Answer 1</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="b" id="q4b"><label for="q4b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="c" id="q4c"><label for="q4c">Answer 3</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="d" id="q4d"><label for="q4d">Answer 4</label><br/>        
</ul>        

<p class="question">5. What is the answer to this question?</p>        

<ul class="answers">            
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="a" id="q5a"><label for="q5a">Answer 1</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="b" id="q5b"><label for="q5b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="c" id="q5c"><label for="q5c">Answer 3</label><br/>           
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="d" id="q5d"><label for="q5d">Answer 4</label><br/>        
</ul>        

<p class="question">6. What is the answer to this question?</p>        

<ul class="answers">            
<input type="radio" name="q6" value="a" id="q6a"><label for="q6a">Answer 1</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q6" value="b" id="q6b"><label for="q6b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q6" value="c" id="q6c"><label for="q6c">Answer 3</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q6" value="d" id="q6d"><label for="q6d">Answer 4</label><br/>        
</ul>       

<p class="question">7. What is the answer to this question?</p>        

<ul class="answers">            
<input type="radio" name="q7" value="a" id="q7a"><label for="q7a">Answer 1</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q7" value="b" id="q7b"><label for="q7b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q7" value="c" id="q7c"><label for="q7c">Answer 3</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q7" value="d" id="q7d"><label for="q7d">Answer 4</label><br/>        
</ul>        

<p class="question">8. What is the answer to this question?</p>        

<ul class="answers">            
<input type="radio" name="q8" value="a" id="q8a"><label for="q8a">Answer 1</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q8" value="b" id="q8b"><label for="q8b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q8" value="c" id="q8c"><label for="q8c">Answer 3</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q8" value="d" id="q8d"><label for="q8d">Answer 4</label><br/>       
</ul>        

<p class="question">9. What is the answer to this question?</p>        

<ul class="answers">            
<input type="radio" name="q9" value="a" id="q9a"><label for="q9a">Answer 1</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q9" value="b" id="q9b"><label for="q9b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q9" value="c" id="q9c"><label for="q9c">Answer 3</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q9" value="d" id="q9d"><label for="q9d">Answer 4</label><br/>        
</ul>        

<p class="question">10. What is the answer to this question?</p>        

<ul class="answers">           
<input type="radio" name="q10" value="a" id="q10a"><label for="q10a">Answer 1</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q10" value="b" id="q10b"><label for="q10b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q10" value="c" id="q10c"><label for="q10c">Answer 3</label><br/>            
<input type="radio" name="q10" value="d" id="q10d"><label for="q10d">Answer 4</label><br/>        
</ul>        

<br/>
<div id="results">            
Show me the answers!       
</div>                

<div id="category1">            
<p>              
<strong>Question 1:</strong> The correct answer is the <strong>Answer 1</strong>.</p>        
</div>        

<div id="category2">            
<p>              
<strong>Question 2:</strong> The correct answer is <strong>Answer 2</strong>.</p>        
</div>        

<div id="category3">            
<p>                
<strong>Question 3:</strong> The correct answer is <strong>Answer 3</strong>.</p>        
</div>        

<div id="category4">            
<p>               
<strong>Question 4:</strong> The correct answer is <strong>Answer 4</strong>.</p>        
</div>        

<div id="category5">            
<p>                
<strong>Question 5:</strong> The correct answer is <strong>Answer 1</strong>.</p>        
</div>        

<div id="category6">            
<p>                
<strong>Question 6:</strong> The correct answer is <strong>Answer 2</strong>.</p>        
</div>        

<div id="category7">            
<p>                
<strong>Question 7:</strong> The correct answer is <strong>Answer 3</strong>.</p>        
</div>        

<div id="category8">            
<p>               
<strong>Question 8:</strong> The correct answer is <strong>Answer 4</strong>.</p>        
</div>        

<div id="category9">           
<p>               
<strong>Question 9:</strong> The correct answer is <strong>Answer 1</strong>.</p>        
</div>        

<div id="category10">            
<p>                
<strong>Question 10:</strong> The correct answer is <strong>Answer 2</strong>.</p>        
</div>        

<div id="category11">            
<p>                
You answered them all right!</p>        
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I faced a big problem on my iOS Coding. My requirement is I have a **HTML** file. That file contain some multiple choice Q&A. I Load that html file in a `UIWebView`. And when I click that answer button I have to retrieve which button is clicked on webView.

I have to retrieve that method from html file.

How is it possible?

Its not a duplicate Q, I already googled on this and whatever i got, its not satisfying my requirement.

My code is like below :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path;
    NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    path = [thisBundle pathForResource:@"Untitled" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *instructionsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
   [_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:instructionsURL]];
  }
  - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
  {
    NSString* returnValue =[theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction()"];
    NSLog(@"returnValue = %@ ",returnValue);
  }
  - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
  {
     NSLog(@" didFailLoadWithError");
  }
```

[image]

But my output is : **Sample_JS[2218:44719] returnValue =**

Please help me out ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code,this is the order that things happen:

1. You load the request in `viewDidload`
2. Your `webview` finished load.So you get the value selected.But at this time.You have not select anything.
3. When you select a item, you did not do anything to tell iOS that you select one

**So,what I suggest is using `WKWebview`,it is good to work withs JS Code.**

1. In your js code,add a button to submit.
   Then in the button action function

   ```
   function submit () {
       var message = //here get all your selected items
       window.webkit.messageHandlers.observe.postMessage(message);
    }
   ```
2. In ViewController,create `WKUserContentController` to handle notification

   ```
   WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc]init];
   WKUserContentController *controller = [[WKUserContentController alloc]
                                      init];
   [controller addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"observe"];
    configuration.userContentController = controller;
   _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame
                             configuration:configuration];
   ```
3. In delegate method,handle js event

   ```
   -(void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController
     didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message {
   //message.body
   }
   ```

**Update whole project**

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
@interface ViewController ()<WKScriptMessageHandler>

@property (strong, nonatomic) WKWebView  * webview;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *path;
    NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    path = [thisBundle pathForResource:@"Untitled" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *instructionsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc]init];
    WKUserContentController *controller = [[WKUserContentController alloc]
                                       init];
    [controller addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"observe"];
    configuration.userContentController = controller;
    _webview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame
                              configuration:configuration];
    [_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:instructionsURL]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webview];
}

-(void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message{
    NSLog(@"%@",message.body);
}
```

And htmlfile

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getFirstSelect(){
    var rates = document.getElementsByName('q1');
    var rate_value;
    for(var i = 0; i < rates.length; i++){
        if(rates[i].checked){
            rate_value = rates[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.observe.postMessage(rate_value);
}
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<p class="question">1. What is the answer to this question?</p>

<ul class="answers">
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">Answer 1</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">Answer 2</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">Answer 3</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d"><label for="q1d">Answer 4</label><br/>
</ul>

<div id="Submit">
     <button onclick="getFirstSelect()">Submit</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When click submit
[image]

This is test project,I believe you can figure out rest by yourself

Comment: i follow your code but i can't understand what is WKWebview. Can u please share me some code for this ?

Comment: http://www.joshuakehn.com/2014/10/29/using-javascript-with-wkwebview-in-ios-8.html Refer to this link.It is a new feature of iOS 8

Comment: - (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController
      didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message {
This method is not calling....

Comment: Can u tell me what is :     [controller addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"observe"];   .. What is observe....?

Comment: observe is the name you use to post `window.webkit.messageHandlers.observe.postMessage`

Comment: Where i have to post this code : window.webkit.messageHandlers.observe.postMessage(observe);
In my HTML file ya where?

Comment: According to my html i have to write this code:         // Execute some JavaScript using the result
        NSString *exec_template = @"$('input[name=\"q1\"]:checked').value();";
        NSString *exec = [NSString stringWithFormat:exec_template, version];
        [_webView evaluateJavaScript:exec completionHandler:nil];

Comment: Hey Dude, its not calling anything.. can u help me ?

Comment: I will try.If i succeed,I will post whole successful codes later

Comment: This is my .js code :   var results = [];
var values="";
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input').each(function(){
     results.push({
         id: this.id,
         value: this.value,
         name : this.name
     });
 });
 $('input').click(function(){
  if(this.type != "button"){
   for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++){
    if(this.id === results[i].id){
     //var val[] = results[i].value.split("_");
     var val = results[i].value.split("_");
     values += "Values Selected: "+results[i].name+" "+val[0]+"  And  Points: "+val[1]+" , ";
    }
   }
  }
 });

Comment: $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
  values = values.substring(0, values.length-1);
  var message = @“observe”;
      window.webkit.messageHandlers.observe.postMessage(message);
  values="";
 });
 $('button').click(function(){
  values = values.substring(0, values.length-1);
  var message = @“observe”;
      window.webkit.messageHandlers.observe.postMessage(message);
  values="";
 });
 
});

Comment: Please check this is correct or not ? I am writing that code in click action

Comment: Thanks its working, But my requirement is I have to retrieve from a .js file. So i write that code in a js file and retrieve like this..<script type="text/javascript" src="answerdetail.js"></script> but its not working. its return (null)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I am able to solve this Big Issue..

First Set the delegate method for your WebView.

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
 if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"ios:"])
 {
    // Call the given selector
    [self performSelector:@selector(webToNativeCall)];
    return NO;
 }
 return YES;
}

- (void)webToNativeCall
{
 NSString *returnvalue =  [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"returnVal()"];
 NSLog(@"returnvalue == %@",returnvalue);
}
```

In javascript file :

```
function getData ()
{
   window.location  = 'ios:webToNativeCall';
}
function returnVal(){
  return values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code , I have tested in my system .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];

}
```

Button action method to check html results after click on radio button -

```
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender {

    NSString* javaScriptString = @"document.querySelector('input[name=\"sex\"]:checked').value;";
    NSLog(@"%@",  [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: javaScriptString]);
}
```

Html Files -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <form action="">
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But I don't have any myFunction() method . I have only that HTML file. In that file there is no onclick method so can u explain how to make this ?

Comment: Ok !! if you click on Radio Button then is there radio button state change to selected  ? Or can you provide html for reference

Comment: Yeah, the radio button will change to selected...I updated my question . plz check.

Comment: Please check above code , i have tested in my system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79391/discussion-between-s-r-nayak-and-santu-c).

Comment: ok Dude, but we don't have the cutton action. right? How can i get that button action on webView ?

Comment: Please see my answer, you can get that button action from my answer@S R Nayak

Comment: @SRNayak    I have place a button just for NSlog value . you can do same using UIWebView touch event

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a global variable in JavaScript which store the value of answer.
your function myFunction() was called after the webview load and when user was selected at that time there are no function called. so you have to call the function rapidly in some time and check it what is the value